# How to use ActiveAdmin in Rails to export a CSV file that will open with multiple tabs in excel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, activeadmin

Here is the [ActiveAdmin documentation for customizing the CSV format](http://activeadmin.info/docs/4-csv-format.html)  I am using ActiveAdmin with my rails app and I would like to be able to download a CSV file that has data in multiple tabs. How can I do this?

Comment: Csv files can't do this. The spreadsheet gem can write xls files with multiple worksheets etc, maybe you can hook that into activeadmin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look at [the spreadsheet gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/spreadsheet) (or [here](http://rubyforge.org/projects/spreadsheet/) for code) then. CSV by itself does not support multiple tabs that I know of. Instead you would want to generate the data as you would for the CSVs and then do a new sheet per CSV:

```
@data_array_normally_for_csvs = #an array of the data hashes you might use for the csvs
book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new

@data_array_normally_for_csvs.each do |data|
     sheet = book.create_worksheet
     sheet.name = "whatever"
     data.each do |k,v|
          sheet1.row(n) =  v #where n is the count for the hash and v is the array of values
     end
end
```

This is just to give you an idea... you would want to dig into the spreadsheet [documentation](http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/files/GUIDE_txt.html), [wiki](http://spreadsheet.ch/) and [examples](http://honoluluhacker.com/2009/06/17/example-sql-report-with-the-ruby-spreadsheet-gem/) on the web to see what works best. There is also [harvesthq's simple_xlsx_writer](https://github.com/harvesthq/simple_xlsx_writer) but I have never used it and it seems much less used than spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of csv option we can use the spreadsheet gem as follows

```html
Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
excel = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
sheet1 = excel.create_worksheet :name => "Sheet1"
sheet1 = excel.create_worksheet :name => "Sheet2"
header1 = sheet1.row(0)
   header1.concat [
       'ID',
       'NAME',
      ]
data_row1 = sheet.row(1) 
data_row1.concat [
          1,
          'Anonymous'
        ]
header1 = sheet1.row(0)
header1.concat [
        'name',
        'id'
      ]
data_row1 = sheet1.row(3)
data_row1.concat [
      2,
      ''
    ]
```